# Apprximation of Bessel Function

Tags: bessel-functions

While I was reading approximation of Bessel Function, I found this article
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF02437596.pdf

Can anyone please clarify what is this 'O' function
[image]

Comment: Look up Big Oh notation.

Comment: See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation